# GAE: Know if a specific task is on the queue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task, task-queue

I have to know if a specific task, specific by parameters on the url, is on the queue or not ... should it's possible ?

I'm using Java !

Thanks :)

Comment: Its possible. How easy it is depends on what type of queue you are talking about. Of course by the time you determine it was on the queue, it could have been removed. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this using [Named Tasks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview#Task_Names).

For example, you could hash the task parameters and set the result as the name. Then if you try and insert a task with the same parameters twice the second insertion would fail.

As mentioned before there are race conditions here, you might want to consider if there is a design where having more than once copy of the same task in the queue at any one time is not going to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TASK Queue REST API for your checking status of tasks in queue

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/rest#method_taskqueue_tasks_list

Alternatively you can code for it in advance, use com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.TaskHandle class to get an handle on the task, and then expose the object through a API